# Showing Validation error below the input field in cakephp3.8

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cake php and started to watch a video tutorial about cake php on youtube but I could only find the cake php version 3.6 whereas I am currently using the 3.8 one.

I have followed all the steps within the tutorial on youtube but in my case at the validation part the error is not showing up below the input field and I dont know why. Are there any options in 3.6 and 3.8 to show the error validation below the input field? Please see the attached [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSnis.jpg) and [What I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh0pd.jpg) pictures.

my codes:

## UsersController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;


class UsersController extends AppController
{

    //User Login

    public function login()
    {
       $this->set('title', 'Login');
    }



    // User registration

    public function registration()
    {
       $this->set('title', 'Registration');

       $users = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->getData(), ['validate' => 'register']);
        // Do work to show error messages.
        $this->set('users', $users);




    }
}
```

## UsersTable.php

```
    <?php 
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{

public function validationRegister(Validator $validator){

    #Firstname
    $validator->notEmpty('firstName');

    #Lastname
    $validator->notEmpty('lastName');

    #Username
    $validator->notEmpty('username')->lengthBetween('username', [4,18]);

    #password
    $validator->notEmpty('password');

    #confirm password
    $validator->notEmpty('confirmPassword')
    ->add('confirmPassword', 'no-misspelling',[
        'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password'],
        'message' => 'Password does not match', 
        ]);

    #email

$validator->notEmpty('email')->add('email', 'valid', [
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email',
    ]);

    return $validator;


}
}

 ?>
```

## Registration.ctp

```
<div class="container container-small mt-5">
    <?php
        //Set form Tempaltes

        $myTemplates = [
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>',
        //'input' => '<input type="{{type}}" class = "form-control is-invalid" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>',
        'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>',
        'error' => '<div class="error-message">{{content}}</div>'
        ];

        $this->Form->setTemplates($myTemplates);


        echo $this->Form->create($users);

        if($this->Form->isFieldError('firstName')){
            echo '
                <br>
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                  Please fill up all the fields.
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                ';
        }else{
            echo '';
    }
        // for multiple forms
        echo $this->Form->controls(
        [
            'Firstname' => [
            'name' => 'firstName', 
            'placeholder' => 'FirstName', 
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'First Name',
            'class' => ($this->Form->isFieldError('firstName')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'
            ],
            'Lastname'  => [
            'name' => 'lastName', 
            'placeholder' => 'Lastname', 
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Last Name',
            'class' => ($this->Form->isFieldError('lastName')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'
            ],
            'Username'  => [
            'name' => 'username', 
            'placeholder' => 'Username', 
            'required' => false,
            'class' => ($this->Form->isFieldError('username')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'
            ],
            'Password'  => [
            'type' => 'password',
            'name' => 'password', 
            'placeholder' => 'Password', 
            'required' => false,
            'class' => ($this->Form->isFieldError('password')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'
            ],
            'Confirm Password'  => [
            'type' => 'password',
            'name' => 'confirmPassword', 
            'placeholder' => 'Confirm Password',
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Confirm Password',
            'class' => ($this->Form->isFieldError('confirmPassword')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'
            ],
            'Email'  => [
            'name' => 'email', 
            'placeholder' => 'Email', 
            'required' => false,
            'class' => ($this->Form->isFieldError('email')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'
            ],

        ],
        ['legend' => 'Registration']
        );


        echo $this->Form->submit('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);


        echo $this->Form->end();


    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include some of the code that you've been using here?

Comment: Thanks!, there you go. I edited my post and attached my  codes.

Comment: The screenshots will be difficult for other users to read and debug. You can copy and paste code that is formatted by placing it between four tilda marks (````) before and after the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited again and hopefully it's fine.

Comment: Looks much better, this will help everyone on stackoverflow understand your issue and hopefully provide a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you and I Appreciate your help.

Comment: I've never used any of that `isFieldError` stuff, and errors display on my forms just fine, thanks to builtin functionality of the Form helper.

Comment: just an update:  my validation works fine. it compares the password in to the confirm password and also check if it is valid email but still the error message of each field does not show below the input field in the registration.

Comment: The key in the fields array passed to `FormHelper::controls()` is supposed to match the entity property name, ie it's `fieldName` not `Fieldname`, `lastName` not `Lastname`, etc., it's what's then being passed to the individual `FormHelper::control()` calls as the first argument.

Comment: Ohhh maaan! I got it. thanks a lot. it works!